# GitKit - Disable change of email address on the Manage Account page

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

My application uses user's email address as the user id. Currently it does not allow users to change their email address. They can create a new account if they need to use a different email address. I'm implementing Google Identity Toolkit (GIT) on my site. For users who use Email/Password for login, the Manage Account page of GIT allows users to change their email address and password. I would like to block changing of email address while keeping the change password option.

Is it possible, and if yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not support this option but if you want to do this at your own risk, you can add the following callback in the widget callbacks config field:

```
callbacks: {
  'uiChanged': function(from, to) {
    if (to == 'passwordAccountManage' && document.getElementsByClassName('gitkit-id-email-info-container').length) {
      document.getElementsByClassName('gitkit-id-email-info-container')[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works for me. I tried to go one step further and hide just the "Update email address" link (and still show the current email address), but it seems like it's not on the DOM yet when uiChanged callback is invoked. So, I can't get its element by class from the DOM. Where can I find the list of all the callback events? I couldn't find this information in the documentation.